# Equality of sets, constructing an element with necessary property

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider the set $[0,1)$  and equivalence relation $\rho$:
$$x\rho y\Longleftrightarrow x-y\in\mathbb{Q} ,x,y\in [0,1)$$
Now, consider the quotient $[0,1) /\rho = \{[x]_\rho : x\in [0,1)\}$ and [assuming Axiom of Choice] the set $A$ which contains *exactly one element of each class*.

Let $q\in [0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q} =: Q$ and define:
$$A_q = \{x+q : x\in A\cap [0,1-q)\}\cup\{x+q-1 : x\in A\cap [1-q,1)\} $$

Show that
$$\bigcup_{q\in Q}A_q = [0,1) $$
Showing $\subset$ is simple, but what about the other way round?
Let $s\in [0,1)$, find a $q\in Q$ such that $s\in A_q$.
It is apparent the set $A$ contains exactly one rational, for they are all contained in $[0]_\rho$. Ok, suppose the rational is $r$.
**Problem1:** What if $s=0$?
$$s = 0 = x+q, x\in A\cap [0,1-q)$$
this is possible if $x=q=0$, but since $s$ is rational, $x$ also has to be rational and the only rational we have to work with is $r$. Furthermore, no matter the choice of $q>0$ we have
$$A\cap [0,1-q)\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset\quad\mbox{or}\quad A\cap [1-q,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset $$
So, let's try
$$0 = x+q-1, x\in A\cap [1-q, 1)$$
Must have  $x+q=r+q=1$. So we have $0\in A_{1-r}$. Great!
**Problem2:** What if $s\in Q$. 
$$s=x+q, x\in [0,1-q)$$
We still need a rational $x$ and $x=s-q$. If $s\geq r$, pick $q = s-r$. Then we would get $s = r+(s-r)$, but that is assuming $r<1-(s-r)$ i.e $r\in A\cap [0,1-(s-r))$
We can also let
$$s = x+q-1, x\in A\cap [1-q,1) $$
Under the assumption $r>s$, we can let $q = s-r+1$ and would have that $s = r+(s-r+1) -1$, but again, is it necessarely true that $r\in [1-(s-r+1), 1)$.
How to fix this?

**Calamity!!** What if $s$ is irrational? We would need
$$s = x+q\quad\quad\mbox{or}\quad\quad s=x+q-1$$
but what guarantees the existence of required irrational $x\in A$?

Comment: If $s\in [0,1)$, there exists a unique $x\in A$ such that $s-x$ is a rational number, say $q$. Then $s=x+q$, therefore $s\in A_q$.

Comment: @zarathustra Oh right, if we assume no such $x\in A$, then that contradicts the construction of $A$. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question and accept the answer, so that the question will disappear from the unanswered list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution lies in the construction of $A$. For every $s\in [0,1)$ there exists unique $z\in A$ such that $s-z\in\mathbb{Q}$. The $z$ is unique because if $s-z'\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $z-z'\in\mathbb{Q}$ i.e $z\rho z'$